# parsley validation message not shown with iCheck - data-parsley-multiple

Tags: validation, parsley.js

I have added a checkbox list in a loop with iCheck.  The html is as follows for checkboxes.

```html
<input class="iCheck out-check" type="checkbox"
       data-parsley-mincheck="1"
       data-parsley-multiple="promo-outs"
       data-parsley-group="outs"
       data-parsley-error-message="You need to check something."
       data-parsley-required = "true"
       data-parsley-trigger="change"
       data-parsley-errors-container='div[id="outerror"]'
       id="outs" name="outs"
       value="1" />
```

And I have a div with the id of "outerror". When I do the validation it fails when no checkbox was checked and works as expected but it does not show the message.

Comment: Tried with data-parsley-errors-container="#outerror" also and no luck

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? If you write `$('div[id="outerror"]')` in the console, do you see the div?